# Run vue-cli-service serve and cucumber tests sequentially

Tags: vue.js, cucumber, playwright

Would anyone know how to run vue-cli-serve , allow the dev server to start and then run my cucumber tests. Right now I have to run two scripts from my package.json in different terminals

```
    scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
   "test:playwright":"cucumber-js --require ./cucumber.js --require ./step-definitions/**/*.js "
  },
```

But I wondered if just one command is possible

I've tried

```
   "test:playwright":"vue-cli-service serve && cucumber-js --require ./cucumber.js --require ./step-definitions/**/*.js "
  },

   "test:playwright":"start-server-and-test vue-cli-service serve  cucumber-js --require ./cucumber.js --require ./step-definitions/**/*.js "
```

But the Vue dev server starts and seems to block anything else starting. I'd like to perhaps pause Cucumber but I don't seem to be able to find how to make the framework pause / wait in  my BeforeAll hook (I'm using  "@cucumber/cucumber": "^9.0.0",   "playwright": "^1.31.2")

Thanks for any comments

Comment: [Playwright says: "Make tests as isolated as possible"](https://playwright.dev/docs/best-practices#make-tests-as-isolated-as-possible). "Each test should be completely isolated from another test and should run independently with its own local storage, session storage, data, cookies etc. Test isolation improves reproducibility, makes debugging easier and prevents cascading test failures."

Comment: I'm not sure how this helps me , perhaps you could expand on your comment ? I need to run my application and then test it and currently  I do not know how to do that .

Comment: The suggestion is to not run tests sequentially, which helps you by offering a different approach. You don't have to take the suggestion and there are exceptions to every rule, but it's at least good to keep in mind that what you're attempting to do can lead to problems.

Comment: Sorry I really do not understand what you are trying to explain. Surely I need to have my application available , that is running on a port so I can test it using my testing framework ?  How else can I test an element is present in a view unless its running on some url (e.g. http://localhost:8080) for playwright to 'page.goto(url) and test it ? So my question is how do I get my vue-cli-service to start the application on http:..localhost:port  and then wait until its avaliable on that url and then run my test suites ?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. There's a difference between running tests and running tests sequentially. Based on your original question, it sounded like running tests sequentially was the main request here.

Comment: OK I see , thanks for taking time to answer.  I finally found a way to do it. My igronance of Vue is obvious!

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have found an answer

1. Use pm2 process manager, yarn add pm2 --dev
2. Run build for you application which creates the dist folder
3. Use the  node scripts below

"test:cucumber": "cucumber-js --require ./cucumber.js --require .//step-definitions/**/*.js ",

"delete-pm2": "pm2 delete all",

"test:playwright": "pm2 serve dist 8080 --spa && npm run test:cucumber  && npm run delete-pm2"

Then run

```
yarn test:playwright
```